# Update the oposite of current boolean value

Tags: laravel

i want to update my active boolean value with the oposite,
`User::where('condition)::update(['active=> !active]);`

when `active=0` , result be `active=1` 
when `active=1` , result be `active=0`

**Just look for a one-line solution**

Answer (score -1):

The best way to update it is to fetch record and then update it as bellow.

```
$user = User::where('condition')->first();
$user->active = !$user->active; OR // $user->active = $user->active ? false : true
$user->update();
```